# Calculate a mean and deal with NA

Tags: r, mean, na

I got a dataset (df) that looks like this:

```
LETTER  |  VALUE  |
A       |   2     |
A       |   3     |
B       |   4     |
B       |   NA    |
B       |   6     |
B       |   NA    |
C       |   NA    |
C       |   NA    |
```

I m looking for a way to create a second datased (new_df) based on the mean of VALUE for each LETTER. But I need to know which letter have NA.

new_df should look like this:

```
LETTER  |  VALUE  |
A       |   2,5   |
B       |   5     |
C       |   NA    |
```

Here is the code I tried :

```
new_df <- aggregate(as.numeric(VALUE) ~ LETTER, df, mean)
```

The issue with it, is that it omit NA and only returns this:

```
LETTER  |  VALUE  |
A       |   2,5   |
B       |   5     |
```

Can you please help?

Comment: definitely a duplicate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may just change defaults of `aggregate()`

```
aggregate(as.numeric(VALUE) ~ LETTER, df, function(x) mean(x, na.rm=TRUE), 
    na.action = na.pass)
```

Comment: or not use the `formula` method: ie `with(df, aggregate(VALUE , list(LETTER), mean,  na.rm=TRUE))` . It would be good if aggregate was consistent